# Add text to a file in between after a particular string

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, echo

I have build.gradle file. I need to search for a string `android {` and if found; on the next line it should echo some contents as `echo "signing config={..SOME CODE.....} > build.gradle`. Is this possible. Using the above code I could echo code from command line , only at the beginning or at the end. Please help me out.

EDIT:

Example...My gradle file is as

```
buildscript {
CODE
}

dependencies {
    CODE
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application`

android {

defaultConfig {
    CODE
}
}
```

Here on detecting `android {` as a string the follwing should be appended after `android {` as below

```
buildscript {
CODE
}

dependencies {
    CODE
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application`

android {

 **HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**
defaultConfig {
    CODE
}
}
```

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Edited the question as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about simple awk?

```
awk '/^android/{print;print "**HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**";next}1' build.gradle
```

'1' at the end might be a bit cryptic, more verbose version:

```
awk '/^android/{print;print "**HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**";next}{print $0}' build.gradle
```

in-place change:

```
{ rm build.gradle && awk '/^android/{print;print "**HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**";next}{print $0}' > build.gradle ; } < build.gradle
```

Comment: When I tried the above in command line ,the text appeared exactly like I wanted in the command line itself. But when I opened my gradle file it has not changed.

Comment: Correct, awk does not work in-place by default. Here is quite typical way to deal with that: `{ rm build.gradle && awk '/^android/{print;print "**HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**";next}{print $0}' > build.gradle ; } < build.gradle` .. or if you have awk>4.1.0 there is an option to do the changes in-place (-i).

Comment: It's working..Thanks.. Can you please update the answer so that I can accept it as correct...

Comment: It's working fine. But when I use the code


`{ rm build.gradle && awk '/^android/{print;print "signingConfigs {

        release {
           CODE
        }
    }";next}{print $0}' > build.gradle ; } < build.gradle`

it was not working

Comment: The issue is with quotes..quotes is not getting printed.

Comment: not sure what quotes do you want to print, but you can escape them like here: `{ rm build.gradle && awk '/^android/{print;print "\"signingConfigs { release { CODE } }\"";next}{print $0}' > build.gradle ; } < build.gradle` . That prints quotes around `signingConfigs { release { CODE } }`.

Comment: `{ rm build.gradle && awk '/^android/{print;print signingConfigs{release{storeFile file('PATH') storePassword 'PASSWORD' keyAlias 'ALIAS' keyPassword 'PASSWORD'}}";next}{print $0}' > build.gradle  } < build.gradle`   
The quotes of capital letter words in the above is not getting printed.

Comment: That should work for you: `{ rm build.gradle && awk "/^android/{print;print \"signingConfigs{release{storeFile file('PATH') storePassword 'PASSWORD' keyAlias 'ALIAS' keyPassword 'PASSWORD'}}\";next}1" > build.gradle; } < build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

A `sed -i` call to edit-in-place will do what you want:

```
sed -i 's/android {/android {\n**HERE THE TEXT ADDED IN THE COMMAND SHOULD APPEAR**/'
```

There are several other variations of the `sed` call you can use to tailor it to your precise needs.